# Showing NINE as a prime number while executing this code.Help me

Tags: java

//Getting Prime numbers from 2 to given range.
  //When Inner for loop is running for number 2, it is printing 9 as a prime number.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class A 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
   System.out.println("Enter the number till which the prime number is to be printed:");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int limit = sc.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Printing the prime numbers from 1 to "+limit);

   for(int num =2; num<=limit; num++)
   {  

      for(int d=2; d<=num; d++)
       {

        if(num%d == 0)
        {
        break;
        }
        if()
        {
         System.out.println(num);
         break;
         }

       }
   }
```

} 
 }

Comment: Erm...how's that even compiling with that malformed `if` statement?

Comment: Moreover even if it were to compile, the index of the inner loop suggests that it would not find a single prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Above the second loop keep a flag as true which means initially the number is a prime number.

```
boolean flag = true;
```

Second loop condition shall be `d <= num/2`

Inside the second loop to `break` if its not prime, or divisible by a number.

```
if(num%d == 0)
{
    flag = false;
    break;
}
```

Outside the second loop, print it if the flag is still true:

```
if(flag){
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

**Remember**: For large scale prime number checking or generation, the algorithm of [Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is always best.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bad news. This program finds not the prime number but the odd numbers: 3, 5, 7, 9 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the values if it is not divisible.
all the non prime numbers from 2 to 8 are divisible by 2 and hence it is showing only prime numbers.
in case when number is 9, it is printing 9 because 9%2 is not 0.